# Get started with the formatting in Monaco Editor

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, monaco-editor

I am trying to add a formatting to a custom language in Monaco Editor. It seems that we could use [monaco.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#registerdocumentformattingeditprovider).

As an example, I have made a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/a151xgFBr5ffxdJGV5Pd?p=preview). Now I want to add a very simple formatting rule to the whole document: **add one newline after each error log**. But I don't know how to write the provider in `mySpecialLanguage.js`:

```
monaco.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider('mySpecialLanguage', {
  provideDocumentFormattingEdits: function (model, options, token) {
    console.log("here") // which is well printed
    // should return a value of type TextEdit[], but I don't know how to construct one
  }
})
```

`provideDocumentFormattingEdits` should return a value of type `TextEdit[]`, where `TextEdit` is specified [here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.textedit.html).
However, I cannot find enough code samples of constructing `TextEdit` in Monaco Editor (there are some examples for VSCode). Could anyone point me to some samples and help me get started?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this what you need,

```js
monaco.languages.registerDocumentFormattingEditProvider('mySpecialLanguage', {
    provideDocumentFormattingEdits: function (model, options, token) {
      let returnData = [];

      for (let i = 1; i < model.getLineCount() + 1; i++) {
        const length = model.getLineContent(i).length;

        // return with text and range. 
        returnData.push({
          range: {
            startLineNumber: i,
            startColumn: length+1,
            endLineNumber: i,
            endColumn: length+1,
          },
          text: '\n',
        });
      }

      return returnData;
    }
})
```